# Make debugger skip code in wrapper class

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

If function Foo() calls function Bar() which calls function Baz(), is there an attribute or something I can add to Bar() to instruct the debugger to ignore the code in Bar() and step directly to the code in Baz() without also stepping into the code in Qux()?

```
void Foo(){ 
  Bar(); // If start debugging here...
}

void Bar(){ // I want to skip this function completely...
  Qux();
  Baz();
}

void Baz(){ // And step to here.
  Zab();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) to do this.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
void Bar()
{ // I want to skip this function completely...
  Qux();
  Baz();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. How can I get it to step from Foo() to Baz() without stepping into Qux()? I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @adam0101 You'd have to decorate `Qux()` to be stepped over, if that's what you want.  Just realize it will ALWAYS step over it.  If this isn't desirable, the only real option is to wrap it in a separate, local method you can decorate...